# pymssql ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have a problem with the follwoing code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import model_from_json
import pymssql
```

## load json and create model

```
json_file = open('model_Messe_Dense.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("model_Messe_Dense.h5")
```

## Import Values

```
import pickle

y_scaler = pickle.load( open( "y_scaler.p", "rb" ))
x_scaler = pickle.load( open( "x_scaler.p","rb"))
```

## Connecting to server and update values

```
while True:
    try:
        conn = pymssql.connect(
            server='SHS_Messe', 
            user='sa', 
            password='sa',
            database='ChillWARE_Transfer'
        )

        stmt = "SELECT screw_speed,\
                        ID,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_1,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_2,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_3,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_4,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_5,\
                        Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_6,\
                        mass_pressure,\
                        Update_Done\
                        FROM to_ChillWARE where ID= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM 
to_ChillWARE)"
    # Excute Query here
        df = pd.read_sql(stmt,conn)

    except pymssql.Error as e:
        print (e)
        break


    feature_col_names = ['screw_speed','Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_1','Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_2','Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_3',\
                     'Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_4','Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_5','Cylinder_Temperatur_Zone_6']
    predicted_class_names = ['mass_pressure']
    Update = ['Update_Done']

    x = df[feature_col_names].values
    Update = df[Update].values
    x_scaled = x_scaler.transform(x)
    x_test = x_scaled

    predicted = loaded_model.predict(x_test)
    predicted = y_scaler.inverse_transform(predicted)

    predicted=predicted.reshape(-1)
    predicted.shape
    predicted=predicted * 51

    value=str(predicted)

    value=value.replace('[','')
    value=value.replace(']','')

    Update = str(Update)
    Update=Update.replace('[','')
    Update=Update.replace(']','')

    if Update == "False":
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        query = "UPDATE to_ChillWARE SET [mass_pressure] ="
        query = query + value + ",[Update_Done] = 1"
        query = query + " where ID= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM to_ChillWARE)"

        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
```

I want to check if i have a connection with a mssql server and if Update == False i want to update values.

On my pc everything works just fine. I executed the code via python and via exe (pyinstaller). But if i want to transfer this to another pc i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 29, in <module>
File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 675, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I think there is a problem with the pymssql function.
I found the same error here but i don't understand the solution:

https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/3035

If anyone could help that would be amazing.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment in the link you provided it looks like a connection error.

Have you checked that from the machine you are trying to use the code you have access to the DB server with the server name provided and those credentials?

Edit with solution from comments below:

You can reuse the connection by defining "conn = pymssql.connect..." outside the while loop and always use that variable, so you are not creating a connection on each iteration.

Comment: The programm works for about 15 Updates in the SQL server, so this means i get a connection. But after some time this error pops up. And when i run the programm from my computer it works fine.

Comment: Then the problem could be you are exceeding the number of connections. If you are doing this in a while loop maybe you are creating a connection each time and not closing it.I think you can reuse the connection and create it only once.

Comment: I tried conn.close() at the end but i get the same result. I don't know how i can read out my data without connecting again to the server. Maybe you have an example or an other idea. When I keep closing the connection it shouldn't stack like you mentioned right?

Comment: Yes, I think that if you close all the connections you opened the problem shouldn't happen (assuming the problem is that the maximum number of connections was reached).
Just make sure you added the conn.close() at the end but also outside the if Update == "False": so every connection gets closed and not only those matching the condition.

If that is not working I'm out of ideas at the moment... :/

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure I understand the implementation and the purpose of the script. It looks like it will run forever and do many queries without waiting. Maybe the server is closing the connection because of that.
Also, what I meant by reusing the connection was to define "conn = pymssql.connect..." part outside the while and always use that variable. Also maybe "cursor = conn.cursor()" could be reused. Not sure about that...

Comment: Your suggestion was right. I had to put the connection bevor the while loop.

should i mark this as correct answer or do you want to make a new post so no one has to look up this comments?

Comment: Great that it worked. I edited the answer so you can mark it as correct.